# Is 'to' a part of infinitive when using 'to + verb' and 'to' has the same meaning as 'in order to'

Tags: grammar, infinitives, infinitive-constructions

Please, take a look at the examples below.

1. I started to cry.
2. I opened my eyes to see them. ('to' = 'in order to')

In the first example the `'to cry'` part is sure an infinitive. 
It corresponds to  **I started + `infinitive`** formula.

The question is about the second example. 
Is it correct that in the second example the `'to see'` part is an infinitive too, that is it corresponds to  **I opened my eyes + `infinitive` + them** formula?

Or does it correspond to  **I opened my eyes to + `infinitive` + them** formula?

Is there an infinitive in the second example? If so, please tell me what it exactly is and explain why.

Comment: CGEL (p727) analyses 'in order' as a preposition taking a that-clause or a to-infinitival. But the comparison with French 'pour' here suggests that the string 'in order to' should at least be considered to be unitary. However, labelling 'in order to', as various authors do, a compound preposition overlooks the real problem of having a bare infinitive as a prepositional object/complement. This extends to considering 'to' as a [simple] preposition here. There is an argument that 'in order to' (along with the deleted form 'to') is a unique type of lexeme.

Comment: @edwin-ashworth   My question in fact has almost nothing to do with 'in order to'. I change the title to make it more clear

Comment: @KannE My question in fact has almost nothing to do with 'in order to'. I change the title to make it more clear

Comment: You're mistaken. If 'in order to' [see them] is analysed as prep + inf, then 'to see them' in parallel constructions should almost certainly be analysed the same way.

Comment: What you're talking about are called Purpose Infinitives. They are always a possible sense for an infinitive phrase, especially when infinitive complements are not allowed. For instance, _stop_ takes a gerund complement, but not an infinitive, so while _He stopped smoking_ means that he no longer smokes, _He stopped to smoke_ can't mean that, so _to smoke_ is interpreted as a purpose infinitive, meaning 'in order to smoke'.